# $X_n$ converges to $X_0$ iff a constant $C_n$ converges to $C_0$

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that the random variable $X_n$ is a constant on $\Omega$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$

I need to prove that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X_0$ as $n\to\infty$ if and only if $C_n$ converges to $C_0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: This problem tests the understanding of the definitions

Comment: Yes I know, but I need a proof of it

Comment: What is $C_n$ and $C_0$?

Comment: @JimmyR. $X_n=C_n$ almost surely, where $C_n$ are constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I preassume that in this context $X_n:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed for $n=0,1,2,\dots$ by $\omega\mapsto C_n$.

Observe that $F_{X_n}(x)=1_{[C_n,\infty)}(x)$.

So you are actually asked to prove on base of $\lim_{n\to\infty}C_n=C_0$ that $\lim_{n\to\infty}1_{[C_n,\infty)}(x)=1_{[C_0,\infty)}(x)$ for every continuity point of $1_{[C_0,\infty)}$.

Observe that $x$ is a continuity point of $1_{[C_0,\infty)}$ iff $x\neq C_0$.

Give this a try and let me know if you get stuck somewhere.